# Using UART of zigbee chip cc2652p in both ways, programming the chip (via usb to UART) and while operating the chip on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, zigbee

Excuse me if this is a dumb question :)

I am designing a pcb that is to be a hat over a raspberry pi to add zigbee functionality. The hat will use zigbee module cc2652p from texas instruments. The chip have RX/TX serial communication capability and this can be used by the serial pins of raspberry pi (prooved working).

At the same time I want to use the TX/RX to program the cc2652p chip first before putting on top of the raspberry pi, by adding a usb to serial chip to the board (CH340 for example), so it can be programmed by texas instruments software and uploading the firmware to it.

I am wondering if this would work?

I may also make a separate programming board that has the ch340 chip on it so the zigbee boards doesn't have to have the ch340 all the time since the programming happens only once in general.